# Introducing: Markdown Shortcuts for Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, mathjax, mhchem

Inserting Mathjax and making posts look nice is rewarding, but it can often be, well, repetitive and boring :( Well, not any more. I have been testing and improving this userscript for quite some time now, and here it is in its first release! :D

#### Markdown Shortcuts for Stack Exchange

Because textual descriptions are boring, here's a video demo of the ninja capabilities: [Video demo](https://www.useloom.com/share/d604a6bc8ba14cc5827f6b7162fee564). In short:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>your choice</kbd> => insert LaTeX command (`text` => `\mathrm{text}`)

  - prepend <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>your choice</kbd>) => inserts LaTeX command with `$` surrounded (`$\mathrm{text}$`)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> => dollar-ifying (`text` => `$text$`)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> => double dollar-ifying (`text` => `$$text$$`)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> => frac-ify (`A/B` => `\frac{A}{B}`)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> => align-ify ([image demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmWFQ.png))

All the commands (hotkeys, insertions) are **completely customizable**. It supports wrapping and unwrapping text, as well as custom caret positioning via the pipe character. If this wasn't enough, this **also works in comment boxes and in chat!** :D

If you're interested in detail in the ninja editor capabilities, here's the detailed [Stack Apps entry](https://stackapps.com/q/7930/51509) for this userscript.

#### **[One-click install userscript](https://github.com/GaurangTandon/MarkdownShortcutsForSE/raw/master/MarkdownShortcutsSE.user.js)**

(read [this page](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) to know how to install userscripts in your browser)

---

#### List of default LaTeX commands

```
Keycode Command
Alt-I   \pi
Alt-R   \mathrm{}
Alt-E   \ce{}
Alt-W   \pu{}
Alt-T   \text{}

Alt-Z   dollarify
Alt-C   double dollarify
Alt-S   frac-ify
Alt-A   align-ify
```

---

Finally, **your feedback is encouraged!** What more additional features or improvements would you like to see incorporated in the userscript, to make editing even easier? Remember, this is a userscript, almost everything is possible, so feel free to ask ;)

Comment: Seems similar to https://stackapps.com/questions/3373/mathjax-buttons ? That script also adds buttons -- perhaps you'd like to roll the extra buttons into that?

I'm not actually sure if it still works, but if it does would love to keep it maintained.

Comment: @Manish hello! Yep, both of these userscripts have the same motivation, but the newer one has several features more than the original one. I had also thought about the buttons, but the problem with them is that the latex command list is user-editable in this case, so it is possible that the number of buttons would overflow into two lines on the toolbar and clutter it :/ if you've anyway of avoiding that, i'm open to suggestions. Perhaps, I could add a button just for the top 4-5 latex commands?

Comment: Hi Gaurang! Thanks a lot for your efforts. I found this only yesterday and it seems to be a real time saver. To insert `$\mathrm{}$`, the combination (`Ctrl+Alt+R`) creates a small $_\circ$ near the `}` which disappears when I backspace once. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2O2j.png) screenshot might be helpful. Is this intentional? Or if possible, could you fix it?

Comment: @GuruVishnu Hey Guru, glad you like this tool. I am unable to replicate the issue though. See image. The [relevant code](https://github.com/GaurangTandon/MarkdownShortcutsForSE/blob/master/MarkdownShortcutsSE.user.js#L42) does not contain a $\circ$ either, so I am not sure why this issue appears. Let me know if it also doesn't work in incognito, i'll ask others in chat then. 
![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh5rv.png)

Comment: I noticed there was no $\circ$ while adding one extra line in your code for a different purpose. I guess that's an issue on my end and it existed even before my edit. It seems all the `Alt` combinations work well, however, now I found multiple issues with the `Ctrl+Alt` commands. Please see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6CpF.png). The same issues exist even when I perform these commands in an InPrivate window. Sorry for the disturbance.

Comment: It's ok @GuruVishnu. I am checking for altkey press in [this method](https://github.com/GaurangTandon/MarkdownShortcutsForSE/blob/master/MarkdownShortcutsSE.user.js#L497), you can search for "altKey". Most probably your alt key is system bound to some other character.