# Why two different print styles for the x's?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, mhchem

Created the rather nasty markup below. Why are there two different print styles for the x's?

`$$\ce{[H+]^4 + (K_{a1} + xC_T)[H^+]^3 +(K_{a1}K_{a2} + (x - 1 )C_TK_{a1}-K_w)[H+]^2 + K_{a1}((x - 2)C_T-K_w)[H+] - K_{a1}K_{a2}K_w }\tag{C4}$$`

renders as

$$\ce{[H+]^4 + (K_{a1} + xC_T)[H^+]^3 +(K_{a1}K_{a2} + ( x - 1 ) C_T K_{a1}-K_w)[H+]^2 + K_{a1}((x - 2)C_T-K_w)[H+] - K_{a1}K_{a2}K_w }\tag{C4}$$

Comment: This was a feature that mhchem had actually considered implementing earlier ;) See [About the scope of mhchem](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3611/about-the-scope-of-mhchem)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are mixing chemistry typeset with maths typeset; I don't think that the mhchem module is set up for this. There is probably much more wrong than what you consider a bug. Assuming $K$ is an equilibrium constant, it should be in italics (it is not with `\ce`) and the subscript should be in upright font (but get interpreted as variables within `\ce`). A similar thing happens to the interpretation of the $x$.
The macro `\ce{ ... }` will always try to interpret its contents as a chemistry or reaction equation; it is not designed to handle anything else. So in your equation, actually only the protons should be wrapped within this macro:

$$\begin{multline}
  [\ce{H+}]^4 
  + (K_\mathrm{a1} + xC_T)[\ce{H+}]^3 
  + (K_\mathrm{a1} K_\mathrm{a2} + (x - 1) C_T K_\mathrm{a1} 
    - K_\mathrm{w})[\ce{H+}]^2\\ 
  + K_\mathrm{a1} ((x - 2)C_T - K_\mathrm{w})[\ce{H+}] 
  - K_\mathrm{a1} K_\mathrm{a2} K_\mathrm{w}
  \tag{C4}
\end{multline}$$

```
$$\begin{multline}
  [\ce{H+}]^4 
  + (K_\mathrm{a1} + xC_T)[\ce{H+}]^3 
  + (K_\mathrm{a1} K_\mathrm{a2} + (x - 1) C_T K_\mathrm{a1} 
    - K_\mathrm{w})[\ce{H+}]^2\\ 
  + K_\mathrm{a1} ((x - 2)C_T - K_\mathrm{w})[\ce{H+}] 
  - K_\mathrm{a1} K_\mathrm{a2} K_\mathrm{w}
  \tag{C4}
\end{multline}$$
```

Comment: Thanks for the formatting lesson.

Comment: @Max The shortcut script from Gaurang ([Introducing: Markdown Shortcuts for StackExchange](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4264/4945)) makes those things easier to type out. It doesn't make the way mhchem treats it's content more easier understood though ;)